# Unable to parse JSON

Tags: json, parsing

I am making a request to an external API from my node server:

```
request("https://api.data.gov/ed/collegescorecard/v1/schools/?id=168421&api_key=", function(error, response, body) {
        console.log(JSON.parse(body));
        console.log(body.metadata);
        console.log(JSON.parse(body.metadata));

    });
```

The first console gives the output:

```
 { metadata: { total: 1, page: 0, per_page: 20 },
  results: 
   [ { '1996': [Object],
       '1997': [Object],
       '1998': [Object],
       '1999': [Object],
       '2000': [Object],
       '2001': [Object],
       '2002': [Object],
       '2003': [Object],
       '2004': [Object],
       '2005': [Object],
       '2006': [Object],
       '2007': [Object],
       '2008': [Object],
       '2009': [Object],
       '2010': [Object],
       '2011': [Object],
       '2012': [Object],
       '2013': [Object],
       '2014': [Object],
       ope6_id: 2233,
       location: [Object],
       id: 168421,
       school: [Object],
       ope8_id: 223300 } ] }
```

The second log gives me an 'undefined'

The third log gives me `SyntaxError: Unexpected token u`

Why? How do I access only the metadata or results field?

Answer (score 2):

you are trying to use body when this is not the json object. You have used JSON.parse only to console log, but haven't stored the value

```
var jsonBody = JSON.parse(body)
console.log(jsonBody);
console.log(jsonBody.metadata);
```

alternatively you could have done this `console.log(JSON.parse(body).metadata);`. You are parsing body as a json and then getting metadata from that parsed json

Comment: Almost right, the OP *has* defined 'body', it's just the string sent as the third parameter of the request callback, not the JS object the second console statement expects